# for-loop R: seq(along=x)

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

How can I tell R to read the values in a vector `rec` (e.g. 159 472 581 1236 ...) in a for loop and not the length of the vector (1:257) ?

My code is:

```
rec=int [1:257] 159 472 581 1236 1295 1491 ....

lon=matrix(data=NA, nrow=length(rec), ncol=1)
lat=matrix(data=NA, nrow=length(rec), ncol=1)

for (i in seq(along=rec)){  
lon[i]<-get.var.ncdf(nc, "lon", c(i,1), c(1,1)) 
}
for (i in seq(along=rec)){
lat[i]<-get.var.ncdf(nc, "lat", c(i, 1), c(1,1))
}
coordstart<-cbind(lon, lat)
```

The code works but the `lon` and `lat` values calculated are relative to `i` 1:257. I need them to be relative to the actual values of the vector `rec`.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `rec=int [1:257] 159 472 581 1236 1295 1491 ....`

Comment: this line does not do anything. it is the vector i want to use in the loop. I just pasted it there to provide all the info

Comment: Maybe you don't need the `for loop`, does this work: `lon <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "lon", c(rec,1), c(1,1))`?

Comment: I guess you want to extract the nc value at rec and write that to position i: `for (i in seq_along(rec)){ r = rec[i]; lon[i]<-get.var.ncdf(nc, "lon", c(r, 1), (1,1)) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify a vector like this in R. Try this

```
    for (i in rec){  
lon[i]<-get.var.ncdf(nc, "lon", c(i,1), c(1,1)) 
}
```

This code works for me.

Comment: this calculates a vector with 29933 values and of those  29676 are NAs. I wanted to avoid all these NAs. Is this possible?

Comment: @sue Maybe `for (i in rec[!is.na(rec)])`?

Comment: still returns a vector with all the NAs